# Incorrect entry in People Pickers causes drop down menu to be ignored

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

Getting a strange issue on a 2007 form within SP2007. I have a non standard drop down list which has validation against it, all working.

The form also includes a people picker. I have discovered that if a user enters an INCORRECT person into the people pick and tries to submit, corrects the person in the people picker and then submits again my Drop Down list value is being ignored.

I can replicate the error pretty much every time now. Does the people pick error checking causing this issue?

S

Comment: So if the form filler adds a correct user the first time the form and your dropdown work fine?

Comment: yes exactly, also this only happens if the user has selected the dropdown first THEN makes a mistake on the people picker...any people picker for that matter...

Comment: What are you updating with the non standard dropdown list? Basically, the standard sharepoint validation is refreshing the page content which is not going to catch your dropdown. There are some ways around it, but it depends on what you are doing.

Comment: The non standard drop down list is a simple lookup and updates the main list.

Comment: It almost seems like a persistence issue. Not sure what would cause it, but I have seen it before and am trying to remember where!

Comment: pretty sure its do with maintaining the values in the postback...

Answer (score 1):

Right finally got to the bottom of this one...effectively the drop down menu I created used its own data source, I had the datasource in the main section of the page and on the postback it was getting lost.

Moved the datasource to the head section of the page with the other data sources and hey presto it worked.

Thanks for the input evil genius, could someone mark this as the answer?

S

Comment: Hmmm thought i had it but no...fixed it on the people picker but will happening on the main submit button it the persons name is incorrect...